# How do I right-align a <span> within a <p> and keep the text inside the <p> centered? (HTML)

Tags: html, css

It's hard to ask this question without a visual reference, so I included a picture below (as well as a code snippet). I'm trying to achieve two things:

1. right-align the blue `<span>` circle inside the yellow `<p>` box
2. keep the text centered in the `<p>` box, independent of the blue circle

This is my code:

```css
.circle {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block
 }
 
 .box {
  background-color: yellow; 
  height: 30px; 
  width: 500px; 
  text-align: center; 
  margin: 10px
 }
```

```html
<p class='box'>This is centered</p>

<p class='box'>This is not<span class='circle'></span></p>
```

I'm not super familiar with HTML, but I tried doing `align-self: right` for the circle, but nothing happened. Not sure what to do.

Here is a picture of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use absolute position.

```css
.circle {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  /* added */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 10px;
}

.box {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 30px;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative; /* should be relative */
}
```

```html
<p class='box'>This is centered</p>

<p class='box'>This is not<span class='circle'></span></p>
```

To center the text vertically and horizontally:

```css
.circle {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  /* added */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 10px;
}

.box {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 30px;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative; /* should be relative */
  
  /* add these to center text vertically and horizontally */
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<p class='box'>This is centered</p>

<p class='box'>This is not<span class='circle'></span></p>
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! What is that "transform: translateY(-50%)"? Does that just move the blue circle all the way to the right?

Comment: `top: 50%` and `transform: translateY(-50%)`  is necessary to center it vertically.

Answer (score 3):

just float:right and add margin to center

```css
.circle {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin: 5px;
}

.box {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 30px;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box2 {
  padding-left: 30px; /* circle width (20px) + circle margin-left (5px) + margin-right (5px) = 30px */
}
```

```html
<p class='box'>This is centered</p>

<p class='box box2'>This is not<span class='circle'></span></p>
```

Comment: but the second text is not centered in your example.

Comment: updated and adjusted with some padding

Comment: I simplified your code.

Comment: nice, looks good